# write document to a file jsoup

Tags: java, file, jsoup, document

I am trying to save the body tag of a Document to a file. This code just saves a blank file. Please help

```
 Document d = Jsoup.connect("https://tin.tin.nsdl.com/oltas/servlet/TanSearch/?appUser=T&TAN_NO=JBPP04182D&TAN_FROM_DT_DD=01&TAN_FROM_DT_MM=10&TAN_FROM_DT_YY=2017&TAN_TO_DT_DD=12&TAN_TO_DT_MM=01&TAN_TO_DT_YY=2018&HID_IMG_TXT=" + captcha + "&submit=Download%20Challan%20file").cookies(cookies).get();

       // System.out.println(d);

        BufferedWriter  writer = null;
        try
        {
            writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("F://test.csi"));
            writer.write(d.select("body").text());

        }
        catch ( IOException e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing exceptions?

Comment: Have you read the [Javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are **not closing the writer**.

```
package so;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document; 

public class JsoupEx {
public static void main(String[] args)  {

        BufferedWriter  writer = null;
        try
        {
            Document d = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com").get();
            writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("/home/Desktop/test.txt"));
            writer.write(d.select("body").text());
            writer.close();  // add this line
        }
        catch ( IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Not closing the writer will keep the updates in buffer and will not be pushed into the document i.e. the buffer will not be flushed.